# Nested controller Resources, how to do update and destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

followed a tutorial to help me create instances within a controller. In other words transactions are created on the envelope controller. Like comments on a blog post.

Everything is working perfectly, but I don't know how to edit a transaction now or destroy one. All I need is to find how to edit an existing thing. Let me show you what I have so far:

in views/envelopes/edit (the form code was copied from where you can create new transactions)

```
 <% @envelope.transactions.each do |transaction|%>
   <%= form_for [@envelope, @envelope.transactions.build] do |f| %> <!--??? NEED EDIT INSTEAD OF BUILD ???-->
     <%= f.text_field :name, "value" => transaction.name %>
     <%= f.text_field :cash, "value" => transaction.cash %>
     <%= f.submit "Submit" %> 
   <% end %>
   <%= link_to "Remove", root_path %>  <!--??? WANT TO REMOVE TRANSACTION ???-->
 <% end %>
```

in routes.rb

```
  resources :envelopes do 
    resources :transactions
  end
```

in transaction controller

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @envelope = Envelope.find(params[:envelope_id])
    @transaction = @envelope.transactions.build(transaction_params)#(params[:transaction])
    @transaction.save

    @envelope.update_attributes :cash => @envelope.cash - @transaction.cash

    redirect_to edit_envelope_path(@envelope)
  end

  def destroy
    # ???
  end

  def update
    # ???
  end

  def transaction_params
    params.require(:transaction).permit(:cash, :name, :envelope_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def update
    @transaction = @envelope.transactions.find(params[:id])
    if @transaction.update(transaction_params)
      redirect to @envelope, notice: 'Transaction was successfully updated'
    else
      redirect_to @envelope, notice: 'Transaction was not updated'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @transaction.destroy
    redirect_to @envelope, notice: 'Text here'
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey! That looks amazing, I want to try it but I'm still not sure how to call these actions from the form_for and link_to

Comment: I think following will work: link_to 'Destroy transaction', envelope_transaction_path(@envelope, transaction), method: 'delete'

Comment: That does work, mostly. once it does call that action in the transactions controller it comes up with undefined method 'destroy' for nil:nilclass. 

So I think the transaction object or instance might not be getting there. I'll keep trying some things, thanks for your help!

Comment: ok, do link_to 'Destroy transaction', envelope_transaction_path(@envelope, @transaction), method: 'delete

Comment: I could see on the error page that id and envelope_id were being past to the controller, not the objects so I added these lines before the rest of the destroy:
'    {at}transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])
    {at}envelope = Envelope.find_by_id(params[:envelope_id])'
however I still don't know what to call instead of envelope.transaction.build in the form_for. Thanks for your help man!

Comment: you should call envelope.transactions.build, (plural form of transactions, not singular)

Comment: oh yes, sorry thats what it is right now, but it calls the Create action not the edit or update action. thats the problem I'm having